# Blender Imported file.OBJ I not showing up

Tags: rendering, mesh, objects, import

I got Blender a few hours ago, and I have been trying to import an .OBJ file, but it's not appearing.

[image: j,]

I have tried to rescale, fix clipping, outline is on, and it's not outside of the plate either.

Comment: Have a look at the system console window, to see if something is traced here.

Comment: @lemon Its traced  Material not found MTL: 'C:\\Users\\jensu\\Documents\\Iris\\GFX items\\Model'
    (  0.0472 sec |   0.0212 sec) Done, building geometries (verts:0 faces:0 materials: 0 smoothgroups:0) ...
    (  0.0832 sec |   0.0572 sec) Done.
  (  0.0842 sec |   0.0772 sec) Finished importing: 'C:\\Users\\jensu\\Documents\\Iris\\GFX items\\Julius Model (Aorcsphere123.obj'
Progress: 100.00%

Comment: Well, it seems some elements are missing in your obj file (or the associated .mtl file).

Comment: @lemon I will try to extract  it again. I'm trying to make a roblox GFX..

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the tree list in the upper right for that object, you can see what materials are attached to it and possibly reattach them without having to re-extract and re-import.

Depending on the size of your object, it may also be hidden by the clipping planes.  When I can't find something, I go to the menu on the right of the 3D window and change the clip to a really high number (usually 1,000,000 or so).  Since the object shows up in the list on the right, another thing you can do is select it in that list, move the mouse back to the 3D window, and hit the period key on the number pad to zoom to that object.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to scale up the model, the scale unit when exported from different software are quite different, especially when imported to blender.
2. If nothing happens, zoom out, and scale down.
3. If this still happens, Try blender 2.83, and re-import again, do the first two steps again.

This happens to me when I import models exported from Marvelous Designer, I tries these steps, it works, hope it will work for you as well.

Good Luck!